# Why does HttpContext.User.Identity.Name contain the wrong name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have a .NET 5 MVC application that periodically checks access based on the HttpContext.User.Identity.Name value. The app uses Azure AD. Sometimes as I switch between users (Signing out and Signing in), the HttpContext.User.Identity.Name value will contain the previous user's name and the current user will have the access of the previous user.

Even more strange is the the login shown is correct.

[image: login name]

This is just the boiler plate code generated by visual studio:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="navbar-text text-light">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

So @User.Identity.Name on the .cshtml is always correct, but HttpContext.User.Identity.Name on the controller is the previous (cached?) user.

Any clues to why the previous user gets cached?

Here is a sample of how I call it on the controller:

```
ViewData["User"] = HttpContext.User;
ViewData["Menu"] = await _menuService.GetReportMenuAsync(MenuService.ReportMenuItemOption.Genesis01, User.Identity.Name);
var userAccess = await _userAccessService.GetUserEntityAccessAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            var model = new SomeModel
            {
                SearchDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7),
                Banks = userAccess.Banks,
                ATMIds = userAccess.ATMs
            };                

            return View(model);
```

This is in my StartUp:

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Comment: Are you storing any values from HttpContext on your controller or a service, and that controller or service is marked as a Singleton for scope? I don't think you have enough info here, especially if you're showing us the part that works.

Comment: I am not storing anything. Whenever I need the current user I type 'HttpContext.User.Identity.Name' in the relevant controller method. I update the post with an example: Is there a difference between 'HttpContext.User.Identity.Name' and 'User.Identity.Name'?

Comment: I do not have anything marked as Singleton (explicitly, maybe something is by default).

Comment: You could try to check whether in any specific browser you are able to reproducing this issue? Try to check for the issue using incoginto private mode. See whether it makes any difference. Further, try to fetch value using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`instead of `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Can you show more of the controllers and/or the services being injected? The constructor  for the controller and the definitions for `_menuService` and `_userAccessService`. If those are just .NET classes with no customizations, feel free to just mention the namespaces they come from.

Comment: The constructor for the controllers are similar to:
public ReportsController(IReportService reportService, IUserAccessService userAccessService, IMenuService menuService, IExceptionLogService exceptionLogService, IEventLogService eventLogService)
        {
            _reportService = reportService;
            _menuService = menuService;
            _exceptionLogService = exceptionLogService;
            _userAccessService = userAccessService;
            _eventLogService = eventLogService;
        }
I created the services but the Identity.Name value is wrong before they are called.

Comment: 'HttpContext.Current' is unavailable in .NET 5

Comment: It is worth checking whether you are only one user who is facing the said issue or other users also facing the issue. Also, if any specific browser causing this issue. In that case, maybe the issue is related to the browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I did not. I ended up porting to .NET 6. I haven't seen the issue so far.

Comment: My issue turned out to be a caching feature of the framework I was using (OrchardCore).